# Problem accessing certain settings when using custom masterpage

Tags: 2013, custom-masterpage

I have a custom master page based on "Responsive Sharepoint" masterpages (https://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/) that I've been working on for a few days now.

Everything looks good and runs smooth up until I try to access certain site settings (site permissions, site collection features, regional settings and most others). I keep getting an

> Sorry, something went wrong

error with the correlation id `f2e9cd9c-e04e-e034-737b-ae09a0bf8e6c`.

The ones I can still access are masterpage selection, people and groups and a few more. Whenever I switch to the Seattle master page this problem goes away.

I suspect this might have something to do with me moving some of the controls around but I can not pinpoint the problem. Any ideas?

Link to code: http://www.1912.is/1912/masterpage.txt

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, the problem lay with the contentplaceholders. Added the ones missing (after enabling error messages) and the problem went away.